# Mongo authentication issues

Tags: mongodb, permissions

Hello i have a new AWS server with a Bitnami MEAN stack.

I'm root user on the server, and i started up mongo on the command line.

when i try to do anything (other than "use test" , or "use admin"), such as "show dbs"

I get the following error:

> show dbs

```
 listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:46
```

I know i'm doing something wrong with regard to permissions, i just dont' know what it is.

when I looked at the mongodb.config, everything looks ok, but i see:

```
  # Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
  #noauth = true
  auth = true
```

Also, possibly relevant, when i try to run  mongod, I get errors about "/data/db" doesn't exist, or if i make the directory, I get "not enough space issues"

thank you for your time.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more server/DB configuration - try the DBA site.

Comment: i've seen this type of question asked often here (it's where i looked first).  What is the DBA site?

Comment: How are you connecting mongo shell? for example just you type in command `mongo` or do you pass host, username and password like `mongo --username admin --pasword pwd`

Comment: I am typing in the command mongo while in the ubuntu shell. it doesn't ask for a password or anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not need to run `mongod` again if it is already running, and chances are that it already is. You are also not saying how you are trying to connect, which is likely your problem.

I would suggest reading the [relevant documentation](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/mongoDB) which explains what the default user authentication is and how to connect:

```
$ mongo admin --username root --pasword YOURPASSWORD
```

Where the default **password** is contained in the documentation page. There is also information on setting up new user for your application.

For more information, see the official MongoDB documentation which has many examples:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-access-control/

Comment: Thank you for the link (surprised i didn't find that one :/)  I'll explore this. For info, I'm logging into my remote AWS server using my pem file.  then i just type mongo on the command line (notably mongod seems to throw an error when i try to run it, so I don't think it's run, and i'm not sure why it needs to run, so clearly i have some stuff to learn. I'll be back. thank you for now!)

Comment: There is a typo in the command example: `--pasword` should be `--password`

Answer (score 5):

You are able to successfully connect to database but you does not have admin privilege for this.

If you know the admin user id and password,You can authenticate by

```
db.auth("user_name",'passwd');
```